# "w | tail" chops text at right margin (78 characters)

Tags: shell-script, terminal, pipe, tty

**Summary:** `w | tail` chops rows after 78th column.

When I run the "w" command, it works as expected. However, when I pipe the output to "tail", it chops the output to **78** columns wide (truncates anything after right margin).

I've checked `set` and `env` for any values of 78 (or 79 or 80), as well as `TERM` (xterm|ansi|vt100), and `stty -a` settings, as well as `tail` and `w` (they look OK).  `$COLUMNS` is set to 209 (but this doesn't matter...I set it to 100 with the same results).

I'm running CentOS 5 (kernel - 2.6.18).  The `tail` and `w` binaries look OK to me.

> /usr/bin/w: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
>   for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

```
CentOS$ cat 80.txt
          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
CentOS$ export COLUMNS=100
CentOS$ w | tail -5 | sed 's/./\./g'
.....................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
...............................................................................
```

Comment: Try `alias w='w | more`. That helped me alot.

Answer (score 8):

When `w`'s output goes to a terminal. `w` queries the terminal driver for the number of columns and adjusts the width accordingly.

When output doesn't go to a terminal such as when it goes to a pipe, it reverts to a fixed width of 80 columns. Versions of `procps` [since 3.3.2](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps/commit/88f485e20acd1a3e26a1b6d9d583c8afc4c12de9) allow to override that default with the `$COLUMNS` environment variable.

Some shells like `zsh` or `bash` set the `$COLUMNS` variable, but don't export it. In them, you can do

```
COLUMNS=$COLUMNS w | tail
```

If you don't want the lines to be truncated at all regardless of how wide the terminal is, you can do:

```
COLUMNS=512 w | tail
```

If you've got an older `w`, you probably won't have any option but to emulate a wide terminal. With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/zpty
zpty W 'stty cols 512 -opost && w'
{zpty -r W} | tail
zpty -d W
```

Other things that can emulate a terminal:

```
ssh localhost -t 'stty cols 512 -opost && w' | tail

expect -c 'set stty_init {cols 512 -opost}; spawn -noecho w; expect eof' | tail
```

Comment: I'm using bash 4.2.0(1), w version procps 3.2.7 in a CentOS 5.3. The COLUMNS var doesn't make any different

Comment: If I export the COLUMNS variable, shouldn't w use that setting?  [tried this]

Comment: `COLUMNS=0` doesn't work for me. However, `COLUMNS=1000` does.

Comment: @Razzlephrazz, yes, though that would affect other commands as well. Your problem is probably that you have too old a version of w to support overriding the width.

Comment: Thanks, Stephane.  Do you know how I can find out how old is my "w" and when is the version where it was fixed created?  This apparently is a bug in the "w" command.  Or perhaps my version of the w command uses another ENV var rather than COLUMNS.

Comment: `w -V` prints the version

Comment: @peterph, `COLUMNS=0` seems to work in 3.3.3 but not in 3.3.4. In 3.3.4 for me, any value greater than 512 causes a warning. Which is why I now suggest 512.

Comment: None of these work for me.  I guess we'll try to find a new w. ;)

Comment: @Razzlephrazz, since 3.3.2 is from early 2012 and Centos 5 is ancient, I'd say it's unlikely to work there indeed. Does the zsh work around not work?

Comment: w -V shows:  procps version 3.2.7
have to check on zsh - we have too many systems for workarounds - would be best to get a properly working w command vs patching

Comment: I'll check with host admins about the latest releases on which hosts, then try it on those (vs my own "ancient" hosts ;)).